# Does Google Hangouts SMS integrate with CiviCRM?

Tags: sms, integration

SMS seems to be hit and miss at the moment, with Twillo and Clickatell as the only choices. Since **Google Hangouts** can be used for SMS, is there a way to use that service, assuming the other two don't measure up? Is there anyone working on this, with an extension in anything resembling usable shape? What would it take, if nothing exists, to create something that uses Hangouts?

Comment: Google Hangouts API doesn't include bulk SMS. They partner with Twilio to power voice and SMS services: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sms/twilio

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this coming up for discussion and suspect the answer to that part of your question is 'no'. In terms of 'where to start', it would be worth looking at the two extensions [Clickatell](https://civicrm.org/extensions/clickatell-sms-provider) and [Twilio](https://civicrm.org/extensions/twilio-sms-provider) but i suspect you have already looked at them.

Third option is to engage the services of a [Professional](https://civicrm.org/providers) or use the core teams [Paid Issue Queue](https://civicrm.org/work-core-team)

Comment: It seems my question has been answered since Google users Twillo to power bulk SMS. I did look at the two existing extensions, but wanted to see if there were other options before putting a lot of effort into this. Unfortunately, if neither Twillo or Clickatell does the job reliably, perhaps what's needed is some work on the existing code to make it more reliable and consistent.